# Getting error "There was a failure executing the send pipeline" for json-encoded pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-pipelines

I am getting the following error while deploying it to my test server:

> There was a failure executing the send pipeline: "NameOfMyApp.XmlToJSONSendPipeline, NameOfMyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a310ca75ebafd97" Source: "Unknown "
> Send Port: "SendPortForNAVtoD365" URI: "D:******%MessageID%.json"
> Reason: The pipeline component Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.JsonEncoder,Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline.Components, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 can not be found. If the component name is fully qualified,
> this error may occur because the pipeline component can not be found in the assembly.

The project is running smoothly at my development server.  Any help??

Comment: That error basically means it can't find the JsonEncoder pipeline component.   That sounds like there is an issue with the BizTalk installation.   Was it a clean install or an in-place upgrade?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. It was a fresh installation. So do I need to ask the IT/Infra team for re-installation?

Comment: One more thing is the JsonEncoder pipeline component available with Biztalk 2013 version? Not Biztalk 2013 R2.

Comment: The JSON Pipeline components were introduced with BizTalk 2013 R2, so no.  Was your Dev environment 2013 R2 and Test 2013? If so, that would explain the error

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you. Is there any way to install the JSON pipeline components in Biztalk 2013? or I have to write custom pipeline components for XML to JSON conversion?

Comment: I suppose it would be theoretically possibly to find the DLLs in BizTalk 2013 R2 and GAC them on the 2013 machine, but it it will have some dependencies, including Newtonsoft, and I would think doing that would not be supported by Microsoft. See this for writing your own, see this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b514a48-1c6f-4758-9dee-f85e6f60233b/json-support-for-biztalk-2013?forum=biztalkgeneral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSon Encoder & Decoder pipeline components were only released with BizTalk 2013 R2.  So if you want this functionality in BizTalk 2013 you will have to create you own custom Pipeline Component to convert XML to JSon (or visa versa) as per this thread [JSON Support for BizTalk 2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b514a48-1c6f-4758-9dee-f85e6f60233b/json-support-for-biztalk-2013?forum=biztalkgeneral)